# How to load multiple files with custom process for each of them?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have several CSVfiles with the same structure:

- data_product_1.csv
- data_product_2.csv
- data_product_3.csv
- etc.

It is clear to me that to obtain a dataframe with all the data concatted together with polars, I can do something like:

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.read_csv("data_*.csv")
```

What I would like to do is to add an extra column to the final dataframe containing the name of the product, e.g.

| data | value | product_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | 1 | product_1 |
| 2000-01-02 | 2 | product_1 |
| 2000-01-01 | 3 | product_2 |
| 2000-01-02 | 4 | product_2 |
| 2000-01-01 | 5 | product_3 |

I'm aware I can load the files one by one, add the extra column and concat them together afterwards but I was wondering if I'm missing some other way to take advantage of polars performances here.

Comment: What is the exact content of the CSV files? Can u give an example to clarify (data_product_1.csv, data_product_2.csv, data_product_3.csv)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're wanting the filename added as a column, e.g.

```py
duckdb.sql("""
from read_csv_auto('data_*.csv', filename = true)
""")
```

```py
┌────────────┬───────┬────────────────────┐
│    data    │ value │      filename      │
│    date    │ int64 │      varchar       │
├────────────┼───────┼────────────────────┤
│ 2000-01-01 │     1 │ data_product_1.csv │
│ 2000-01-02 │     2 │ data_product_1.csv │
│ 2000-01-01 │     3 │ data_product_2.csv │
│ 2000-01-02 │     4 │ data_product_2.csv │
│ 2000-01-01 │     4 │ data_product_3.csv │
│ 2000-01-02 │     5 │ data_product_3.csv │
└────────────┴───────┴────────────────────┘
```

This has been requested a few times but is yet to be added to Polars: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9096

You can replace `read_csv` with [`scan_csv`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html) which delays reading the file and returns a [LazyFrame](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/concepts/lazy-vs-eager/) instead.

The frames can be combined with [concat](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html#polars.concat) which (by default) "computes" LazyFrames in parallel.

```py
from pathlib import Path

# lazyframes
csvs = [
    pl.scan_csv(f).with_columns(product_code=pl.lit(f.name))
    for f in Path().glob("data_*.csv")
]

# inputs are read in parallel
df = pl.concat(csvs).collect()
```

```py
shape: (6, 3)
┌────────────┬───────┬────────────────────┐
│ data       ┆ value ┆ product_code       │
│ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---                │
│ str        ┆ i64   ┆ str                │
╞════════════╪═══════╪════════════════════╡
│ 2000-01-01 ┆ 1     ┆ data_product_1.csv │
│ 2000-01-02 ┆ 2     ┆ data_product_1.csv │
│ 2000-01-01 ┆ 3     ┆ data_product_2.csv │
│ 2000-01-02 ┆ 4     ┆ data_product_2.csv │
│ 2000-01-01 ┆ 4     ┆ data_product_3.csv │
│ 2000-01-02 ┆ 5     ┆ data_product_3.csv │
└────────────┴───────┴────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Just to point out that the reason to `concat` `scan_csv` rather than `read_csv` is that concating lazyframes executes them in parallel so this isn't just "opening them one by one" it's opening them in parallel.

Comment: Thanks @DeanMacGregor - I could have explained it better.